# Find rows that exist in one table and not the other

Tags: sql, dataframe

```
CREATE TABLE final(
  FileID int,
  rate varchar(50),
  groupID varchar(50),
  destination varchar(50),
  Rate int,
  bDate date,
  eDate date,
  billID varchar(50) NULL
 );
 
 CREATE TABLE temp(
  FileID int,
  rate varchar(50),
  groupID varchar(50),
  destination varchar(50),
  Rate int,
  bDate date,
  eDate date,
  billID varchar(50) NULL
 );
 
 
 INSERT final VALUES (1,'123','1033','987',2,'2020-01-01','2020-12-31',NULL);
 INSERT final VALUES (1,'234','1052','985',2,'2020-01-01','2020-12-31',NULL);
 INSERT final VALUES (1,'999','1033','988',1,'2021-01-01','2021-12-31','0/1/1');
 INSERT final VALUES (2,'222','1033','989',2,'2022-01-01','2022-12-31',NULL);
 
 INSERT temp VALUES (1,'123','1033','987',2,'2020-06-06','2020-12-31','0/1/1');
 INSERT temp VALUES (1,'999','1033','988',1,'2021-01-01','2021-12-31','0/1/1');
 INSERT temp VALUES (2,'222','1033','989',2,'2022-01-01','2022-12-31','0/1/1');
```

Assuming I have these two tables, I want to do 2 queries.

1. Find the rows that are in final table but NOT in temp table based on their FileID
   Assuming we're only looking at FileID = 1

| FileID | rate | groupID | destination | Rate | bDate | eDate | billID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 1033 | 987 | 2 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-12-31 | NULL |
| 1 | 234 | 1052 | 985 | 2 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-12-31 | NULL |

2. Find all rows that are in the temp table but NOT in the final table based on their FileID. Assuming we're only looking at FileID = 1

| FileID | rate | groupID | destination | Rate | bDate | eDate | billID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 1033 | 987 | 2 | 2020-06-06 | 2020-12-31 | 0/1/1 |

Is there an efficient query that can do this?

Comment: Your description and expected outcome do not match.

Comment: The final outcome is based on FileID = 1 . I'm not including FileID = 2 inside. @Popeye

Comment: But 123 is present in both tables. Why it is appearing in expected output?

Comment: The bDates are different. @Popeye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Left join, then select rows with null for the other table.

Here is an example. I've put in [etc] instead of typing out all the field names.

```
SELECT final.fileId, final.rate [etc]
FROM
( 
SELECT final.fileId, final.rate [etc] temp.FileId
FROM final LEFT JOIN temp
ON final.FileId = temp.FileId, final.rate = temp.rate [etc] 
)
WHERE
temp.FileId IS NULL
```